# Removing a file from TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Am having problems removing a file from Tortoise.

I make the clone, and there are a few test files which I want out. What is the proceedure for removing a file from the repository,

thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide more info. "Is not working" is bad description.

Comment: You might get a better answer at Super User: http://superuser.com/

Comment: sorry "is not working" yup my bad, spent too long with the client recently - listening to the way they speak its obviously rubbed off on me

Comment: btw - solved this by finding an element in the rightclick dropdown list for removing files, and then synchronising the repo. hadnt realised there was more in the drop list.

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on the file(s) and click the **TortoiseHg --> Remove Files..**. and then confirm the dialog. Commit to save the change to your local repository. Note that this will delete the file from disk and from Mercurial.

If you'd like to remove a file from Mercurial but keep the file on disk, you can click **TortoiseHg --> Forget Files...**. Then you may want to add the file to your .hgignore list (you can do this graphically through the Commit or View File Status dialogs) so that you don't add it accidentally in the future. Then commit.